# Glass Recycling Case Study

Tags: recycling, glass, upcycling

Does anyone have a case study on community glass recycling.  Specifically the cost/ton to crush/pulverize and screen into usable traction control sand for winter applications?

Comment: Not to be mean, but didn't you find anything in the [409000 Google search results for 'cost pulverizing glass'](https://www.google.nl/search?q=cost+pulverizing+glass)?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://epa.ohio.gov/Portals/41/recycling/OhioGlassRecyclingStudy.pdf) there is a very interesting case study by the government of Oregon. It is not as specific as you want but they give a lot of figures to understand the cost of processing and collecting glass and to give a quantitative estimate of the average saving caused by recycling.

You can find much more examples [googling](https://www.google.es/search?q=glass%20reciclying%20case%20study&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=AzuxVtGOE4jYaYvShegN#q=glass%20recycling%20case%20study) , like this [British](https://www.foe.co.uk/sites/default/files/downloads/recycling_in_action.pdf) one, which is much more general (they consider different residues, not just glass) and more qualitative than quantitative.